# C# delegate scope

Tags: c#, delegates, scope

This is just a simple example..

I have a Console Display class (that displays information to the console), and an input class (that gathers input from the user). Every time a certain input is received, the console display class will display a specific message.

I'm new to C#, and delegates and my question is, is it safe to declare a delegate on the Console Display Class, point it to a output method in the Console Display Class

```
(DisplayMessage( String msg) )
```

Pass this delegate to the input class in the Input Class Constructor

`InputClass( DelegateName displayDel)
{ m_thisDelegate = displayDel}`

Where `m_thisDelegate` is a member variable of `InputClass`, so that all methods of input class can access the `DisplayMessage` method on the Console Display class?

Comment: it's OK, delegate is just a reference type so it's OK.

Comment: The only thing unsafe about it is your choice of the variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's as safe as declaring any other reference type, there's really no difference.